# Why am I getting an illegal start of expression here?

Tags: java

I'm getting an illegal start of expression on my `public String makeChange(int amount) {` method here.
I'm making a change dispensing program, and am kind of stuck here, I think I'm going about doing it right but am getting this error.

```
package changedispenser;

public class ChangeDispenser {


private static int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
private static int penniesLeft, nickelsLeft, dimesLeft, quartersLeft;
private static int pennyRollsAdded = 1;
private static int nickelRollsAdded = 1;
private static int dimeRollsAdded = 1;
private static int quarterRollsAdded = 1;
public static final int PENNIES_PER_ROLL = 50;
public static final int NICKELS_PER_ROLL = 40;
public static final int DIMES_PER_ROLL = 50;
public static final int QUARTERS_PER_ROLL = 40;

public static void main(String[] args) {



public String makeChange(int amount) {


    if (amount > 99 || amount < 0) {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    quarters = amount / 25;

    amount = amount % 25;

    dimes = amount / 10;

    amount = amount % 10;

    nickels = amount / 5;

    amount = amount % 5;

    pennies = amount;




    do {

        if (quarters != 0) {
            System.out.print("  Quarters: " + quarters);
        }
        if (dimes != 0) {
            System.out.print("  Dimes: " + dimes);
        }
        if (nickels != 0) {
            System.out.print("  Nickels: " + nickels);
        }
        if (pennies != 0) {
            System.out.println("  Pennies: " + pennies);
        }





        //Fix this so that it outputs the appropriate change IE: 23 cents is 2 dimes 3 pennies 


        System.out.println("Coins Left:");
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + quartersLeft);
        System.out.println("Dimes:    " + dimesLeft);
        System.out.println("Nickels:  " + nickelsLeft);
        System.out.println("Pennies:  " + penniesLeft);
        System.out.println("Rolls Added: ");
        System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarterRollsAdded);
        System.out.println("Dimes:    " + dimeRollsAdded);
        System.out.println("Nickels:  " + nickelRollsAdded);
        System.out.println("Pennies:  " + pennyRollsAdded);
    } while (amount > 0 && amount <= 99);


    return "Quarters: " + quarters + "  Dime: " + dimes + "   Nickels: " + nickels + "   Pennies: " + pennies;

}

public int getPenniesLeft() {
    return penniesLeft;
}

public void setPenniesLeft(int penniesLeft) {
    this.penniesLeft = penniesLeft;

    if (penniesLeft <= 0) {
        pennyRollsAdded = pennyRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getNickelsLeft() {
    return nickelsLeft;
}

public void setNickelsLeft(int nickelsLeft) {
    this.nickelsLeft = nickelsLeft;

    if (nickelsLeft <= 0) {
        nickelRollsAdded = nickelRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getDimesLeft() {
    return dimesLeft;
}

public void setDimesLeft(int dimesLeft) {
    this.dimesLeft = dimesLeft;

    if (dimesLeft <= 0) {
        dimeRollsAdded = dimeRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getQuartersLeft() {
    return quartersLeft;
}

public void setQuartersLeft(int quartersLeft) {
    this.quartersLeft = quartersLeft;

    if (quartersLeft <= 0) {
        quarterRollsAdded = quarterRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getPennyRollsAdded() {
    return pennyRollsAdded;
}

public void setPennyRollsAdded(int pennyRollsAdded) {
    this.pennyRollsAdded = pennyRollsAdded;
}

public int getNickelRollsAdded() {
    return nickelRollsAdded;
}

public void setNickelRollsAdded(int nickelRollsAdded) {
    this.nickelRollsAdded = nickelRollsAdded;
}

public int getDimeRollsAdded() {
    return dimeRollsAdded;
}

public void setDimeRollsAdded(int dimeRollsAdded) {
    this.dimeRollsAdded = dimeRollsAdded;
}

public int getQuarterRollsAdded() {
    return quarterRollsAdded;
}

public void setQuarterRollsAdded(int quarterRollsAdded) {
    this.quarterRollsAdded = quarterRollsAdded;
}
}
```

new code, here it is
              package changedispenser;

```
 public class ChangeDispenser {

private static int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
private static int penniesLeft, nickelsLeft, dimesLeft, quartersLeft;
private static int pennyRollsAdded = 1;
private static int nickelRollsAdded = 1;
private static int dimeRollsAdded = 1;
private static int quarterRollsAdded = 1;
public static final int PENNIES_PER_ROLL = 50;
public static final int NICKELS_PER_ROLL = 40;
public static final int DIMES_PER_ROLL = 50;
public static final int QUARTERS_PER_ROLL = 40;

public static void main(String[] args) {
       if (quarters != 0) {
    System.out.print("  Quarters: " + quarters);
    }
    if (dimes != 0) {
    System.out.print("  Dimes: " + dimes);
    }
    if (nickels != 0) {
    System.out.print("  Nickels: "+ nickels);    
    }
    if (pennies !=0) {
    System.out.println("  Pennies: " + pennies);    
    }




}
 ChangeDispenser() {
    quartersLeft = QUARTERS_PER_ROLL;
    dimesLeft = DIMES_PER_ROLL;
    nickelsLeft = NICKELS_PER_ROLL;
    penniesLeft = PENNIES_PER_ROLL;
    pennyRollsAdded = 1;
    nickelRollsAdded = 1;
    dimeRollsAdded = 1;
    quarterRollsAdded = 1;
}






public int getPenniesLeft() {
    return penniesLeft;
}

public void setPenniesLeft(int penniesLeft) {
    this.penniesLeft = penniesLeft;

    if (penniesLeft <= 0) {
        pennyRollsAdded = pennyRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getNickelsLeft() {
    return nickelsLeft;
}

public void setNickelsLeft(int nickelsLeft) {
    this.nickelsLeft = nickelsLeft;

    if (nickelsLeft <= 0) {
        nickelRollsAdded = nickelRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getDimesLeft() {
    return dimesLeft;
}

public void setDimesLeft(int dimesLeft) {
    this.dimesLeft = dimesLeft;

    if (dimesLeft <= 0) {
        dimeRollsAdded = dimeRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getQuartersLeft() {
    return quartersLeft;
}

public void setQuartersLeft(int quartersLeft) {
    this.quartersLeft = quartersLeft;

    if (quartersLeft <= 0) {
        quarterRollsAdded = quarterRollsAdded++;
    }
}

public int getPennyRollsAdded() {
    return pennyRollsAdded;
}

public void setPennyRollsAdded(int pennyRollsAdded) {
    this.pennyRollsAdded = pennyRollsAdded;
}

public int getNickelRollsAdded() {
    return nickelRollsAdded;
}

public void setNickelRollsAdded(int nickelRollsAdded) {
    this.nickelRollsAdded = nickelRollsAdded;
}

public int getDimeRollsAdded() {
    return dimeRollsAdded;
}

public void setDimeRollsAdded(int dimeRollsAdded) {
    this.dimeRollsAdded = dimeRollsAdded;
}

public int getQuarterRollsAdded() {
    return quarterRollsAdded;
}

public void setQuarterRollsAdded(int quarterRollsAdded) {
    this.quarterRollsAdded = quarterRollsAdded;
}
public String makeChange(int amount) {


    if (amount > 99 || amount < 0) {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    quarters = amount / 25;

    amount = amount % 25;

    dimes = amount / 10;

    amount = amount % 10;

    nickels = amount / 5;

    amount = amount % 5;

    pennies = amount;




    do {

        if (quarters != 0) {
            System.out.print("  Quarters: " + quarters);
        }
        if (dimes != 0) {
            System.out.print("  Dimes: " + dimes);
        }
        if (nickels != 0) {
            System.out.print("  Nickels: " + nickels);
        }
        if (pennies != 0) {
            System.out.println("  Pennies: " + pennies);
        }
    } while (amount > 0 && amount <= 99);

   return "Quarters: " + quarters + "  Dime: " + dimes + "   Nickels: " + nickels + "   Pennies: " + pennies;

}
public void writeReport() {


    System.out.println("Coins Left:");
    System.out.println("Quarters: " + quartersLeft);
    System.out.println("Dimes:    "+ dimesLeft);
    System.out.println("Nickels:  " + nickelsLeft);
    System.out.println("Pennies:  " +penniesLeft);   
    System.out.println("Rolls Added: ");
    System.out.println("Quarters: "+ quarterRollsAdded);
    System.out.println("Dimes:    " + dimeRollsAdded);
    System.out.println("Nickels:  " + nickelRollsAdded);
    System.out.println("Pennies:  " + pennyRollsAdded);





}

}
```

Here is a seperate driver class to run the program.

```
 package changedispenser;

  import java.util.Random;


 public class ChangeDispenserDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChangeDispenser changeMachine = new ChangeDispenser();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int amount;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        amount = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;
        System.out.println("Amount: " + amount + ": Change = " +   changeMachine.makeChange(amount));
    }
    changeMachine.writeReport();
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't closed main method

Answer (score 6):

You're creating a method inside of another method, a no-no:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

public String makeChange(int amount) {
```

This is one place where good code formatting helps. Your formatting is not so good with lack of regular and sensible indentation. Put in the effort to format your code well and it will pay you dividends.

For instance, you'd see immediately:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   public String makeChange(int amount) {
     //...
   }

   // ...

}
```

... that you're nesting methods.

---

**Edit**:

Regarding your latest code, I can't say that I went through all of it, but this is very dangerous:

```
  do {
     if (quarters != 0) {
        System.out.print("  Quarters: " + quarters);
     }
     if (dimes != 0) {
        System.out.print("  Dimes: " + dimes);
     }
     if (nickels != 0) {
        System.out.print("  Nickels: " + nickels);
     }
     if (pennies != 0) {
        System.out.println("  Pennies: " + pennies);
     }
  } while (amount > 0 && amount <= 99);
```

Your loop depends on amount changing to a value that allows the loop to end, but where do you actually change amount **inside** of the loop? If you don't change amount inside of the loop, how will it ever exit the loop. You don't, and so the loop could (and does) loop forever.

Comment: "good code formatting helps" -- This isn't emphasized enough.

Comment: Ah thankyou, I've changed my code, here is what it looks like now,

Comment: Ah, now that I've fixed my code, its not outputting anything, but the build is successful, I can't show you my new code though in this comment because it's too long :/

Comment: @user2934545: all code should go as edits to your question. Don't delete the code already there, else the answers will no longer make sense, but rather add the new code to the bottom of your question.

Comment: Alright I added it, but I'm not getting any output in my program.

Comment: @user2934545: regarding your new code: again formatting is something to take serious. **Every** block of code needs to be indented and indented the same amount, I usually use 2-3 spaces (pick one and stick with it through the program). 1 empty line is more than sufficient. **Please**, if you're going to post code here, put some effort into formatting it well. Not sure how to say this so you'll believe me and follow this advice.

Comment: @user2934545: I ran your new code, and it goes into an infinite loop and never stops outputting the same output.

Comment: @user2934545: see edit to answer regarding your infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hovercraft is right, the way you would fix it is to separate them

```
public static void main (String[]args){
     System.out.println(makeChange(5));
}

public String makeChange(int amount){
    ....
}
```